# JSON.NET changes type of a System.Object property automatically to System.String

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a class named `Arg`.
The Property `ArgValue` is of the Type `System.Object`.

```
public class Arg
{
    public string ArgName { get; set; }
    public object ArgValue { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to deserialize a JSON-string like this:

```
string json = @"{""ArgName"":""arg"",""ArgValue"":""/something/more/than/a/string/""}";

var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { };

Arg arg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Arg>(json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

I get the Arg object with its values like this:

- `ArgName` is of type `string` -> `arg`
- `ArgValue` is of type `object    {string}` -> `/something/more/than/a/string/`

I do not want that JSON.NET is converting it into `System.String`.
If the property is of type `System.Object` it should not convert it into a string.

It would be better it leaves it untouched and the value would be of type: **JToken** (or **JValue**).

Is there a JsonSerializerSettings option to configure this behaviour?

**Additional information:**

The string value in the property `ArgValue` is "more than a string" and I need to convert it later by myself. `JsonConverter` cannot be used here, because i do not know the concrete type of the object at this point. later i know and need to use `JToken.ToObject<MySpecialType>()`. (Than it gets correctly converted by a `JsonConverter`).

Comment: well, conversion between string and object means boxing an unboxing, but in your case, the json contains strings, not objects, so it already does what you want to acheive.

Comment: Well that's because there is no need for parsing string value - string is also object. If You need particular type specify it, if You don't know the type use generics.

Comment: Please specify why do You want this behavior ?

Comment: The string value in the property "ArgValue" is "more than a string" and I need to convert it later by myself. JsonConverter cannot be used here, because i do not know the concrete type of the object at this point. later i know and need to use JToken.ToObject<MySpecialType>(). (Than it gets correctly converted by a JsonConverter).

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in the comment, the json string you want to deserialize will be deserialized into an object of a class with two properties, both of type string. This is because when you specify `"ArgName" : "arg"` the two quotes between `arg` mark a value of type string. This is also the case of `ArgValue` which is serialized also as a string.

By doing this line of code:

```
Arg arg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Arg>(json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

You receive an object (`arg`) of type `Arg` which is exactly as a classical object of type `Arg`. It is the equivalent of doing:

```
Arg arg = new Arg{ ArgName = "arg", ArgValue = "/something/more/than/a/string/" };
```

The string assignation of property `ArgValue` which expects an object is the same in the case of deserialize, it is no conversion (or better said *cast*) involved, it is only [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Comment: @user437899 excuse me, how is it created, as with object property?

Comment: sorry I pressed "enter" and the comment was added before I was finished :-)

Comment: On the client-side the class is created like this: Arg arg = new Arg{ ArgName = "arg", ArgValue = new QualifiedName("/something/more/than/a/string/") }; The value is of type "namespace.Qualifiedname". On the server-side it should be the same type, after all pipeline-steps. First is parsing and later it should use the JsonConverter implementation to change the type. But i do not know the type of the property "ArgValue" at the time of deserializing/parsing.

Comment: @user437899 I suggest you to keep it as an `object` as you did, because if you do not know it's type in the moment when you deserialize this property, then storing as an object, then casting it after is the only thing you can do. You can try to deserialize as a `dynamic` type, but it will be less safe.

Comment: Okay thank you. the only way I see is to deserialize the object by myself at a "lower level" and then I can decide how the property is deserialized. (It should be of the type JToken)

Comment: @user437899 for this cases I would use in the `JsonSerializerSettings` `TypeNameHandling.All`, but it will not be useful since the type, as you say, is not known at deserialize. Of course you can do a lot of tricks, and deserialize as the type you want, but it will be almost similar to a cast to the type you need, after a deserialize to object.

Comment: yea i know the typehandling switch, but we decided not to use it (traffic and that it is not a standard). We know the type on the server-side, so it looks like I have to do some tricks here :-)

Comment: @user437899 I know, and I am sorry there is nothing else I can recommend in this case.

Comment: No Problem :-) Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

For later conversion you can use

### Generics

```
public class Arg<T>
{
    public string ArgName { get; set; }
    public T ArgValue { get; set; }
}
```

then you can pass target type as follows:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Arg<Qualifiedname>>(somestring);
```

or

```
public Arg<T> Deserialize<T>(string somestring){
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Arg<T>>(somestring);
}
```

### Leave it as `JToken`

```
public class Arg
{
    public string ArgName { get; set; }
    public JToken ArgValue { get; set; }
}
```

### Deserialize it later with `JsonConvert`

```
public class Arg
{
    public string ArgName { get; set; }
    public string ArgValue { get; set; }
}
```

or simply pass it whole as string until you know what type is going to be parsed..

Comment: I cant make the property JToken, becuase the class "Arg" is a DTO class that is used by other transfer formats aswell.

Comment: Could you use Generics or later Deserialization then ?